# What's the best way in Ruby to clean up a user-provided url string so that it's safe to interpolate into a shell command?

Tags: ruby, curl, code-injection

I want to let a user of a web app enter a URL and then pass that URL onto curl. I'd rather use curl than Net::HTTP or open-uri. But this poses a security risk. What's the best way to check the URL string and prevent any injection attacks?

I'm thinking of just using a regular expression like this to check for an injection attack:

```
raise "possible injection attack" if url =~ /[\s']/
```

and if that check succeeds, then just invoke curl like so

```
html = `curl '#{url}'`
```

Is this safe enough?

Comment: That seems like a Bad Idea (tm) ... what is your aversion to downloading the HTML with ruby?  If you're looking for simplicity, check out http://curb.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I find the documentation for Net::HTTP pretty hard to navigate and understand compared to curl's manpage. Is there something wrong with trying to delegate work from a Ruby program to another unix program?

Comment: I also know about open-uri, but often I want to do things the http response and request headers, and using curl is easier than using Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system("curl", url)
```

this is safe because parameters are directly passed to the `main(argv)` of the command rather than being parsed by a command line processor. For example `system("echo", "* && echo shenanigan")` literally outputs `* && echo shenanigan`.

Comment: Thanks. I think `system(cmd [, arg, ...])` is more what I was looking for but you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: True enough, I keep confusing the two: `exec` replaces the current script with the command, while `system` continues the script afterwards. Fix'd.

Comment: It seems to frustrate injection attacks, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

e.g. ruby -e 'exec("echo", "* && echo \"test\" ")'
outputs this literally:
* && echo "test"

Comment: The command is directly called, imagine calling `main(argv)` with an array of strings, rather than passing a command line to the command line processor. In deed, @dan's example outputs the parameter literally.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're better off using a library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ruby/) (to avoid having to use shell commands) ?

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that, but I'm still interested in the answer to my original question as a matter of general technique, since there are a lot of unix tools I would be able to love to reuse from Ruby.

Comment: I guess it's probable to assume most popular unix tools will have Ruby bindings for them (I know this is certainly the case with Python).

Comment: Is there something seriously wrong with wanting to use Ruby (or Python) as glue code that invokes and orchestrates small external programs via the shell? It seems that there is a strong bias here against that, although the Unix Philosophy used to encourage this sort of style.